# How to handle the situation if one iterator runs out while iterating through multiple lists in python using zip?

Tags: python, arrays, list, zip

here is the code:-

```
array1 = [["a","b","c"] ,['e','f','g'] , ['i','j','k']]
array2 = ['d' , 'h']
array1 = [a+list(b) for a,b in zip(array1,array2)]
print(array1)
```

I want the desired output [["a","b","c", "d"] ,['e','f','g','h'] , ['i','j','k']] but the code gives the optput [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']].

This is happening because there is nothing to add to in array1[2], how to overcome this situation,
I tried using `a = [a+list(b) if b else a for a,b in zip(array1,array2)]` but there was no change please help.

Answer (score 3):

`zip` ends prematurely in this case. You can use `itertools.zip_longest` instead, with a default `fillvalue`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
print([a+b for a, b in zip_longest(array1, map(list, array2), fillvalue=[])])
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do using simple for loop

```
array1 = [["a","b","c"] ,['e','f','g'] , ['i','j','k']]
array2 = ['d' , 'h']
for i in range(len(array2)):
     array1[i].append(array2[i]) #[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k']]
print(array1)
```

And also using list comprehension

```
array1 = [array1[i]+[array2[i]] if i<len(array2) else array1[i] for i in range(len(array1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
array1 = [["a","b","c"] ,['e','f','g'] , ['i','j','k']]
array2 = ['d' , 'h']
A=array1[0]
B=array1[1]
A.append(array2[0])
B.append(array2[1])

print(array1)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k']]
```